# Can't link ml64 compiled assembly file using link.exe

Tags: windows, assembly, gcc, x86-64, msvcrt

## **The issue!**

I have started learning assembly language and am facing some difficulty compiling my program.

```
option casemap:none
.data
fmtStr byte 'Hello, world!', 10, 0

.code
externdef printf:proc

main proc
    sub rsp, 56
    lea rcx, fmtStr
    call printf
    add rsp, 56

    ret
main endp
    end
```

I have successfully compiled my assembly file to object file using the following command.

```
ml64 /c main.asm
```

The problem arises when I try to compile the resulting `main.obj` using the following command.

```
link main.obj /subsystem:console /entry:main /out:main.exe
```

The printf symbol was missing. So
I did some research and found that I need to link `kernel32.lib`, `legacy_stdio_definitions.lib` and `msvcrt.lib` to get this to work. So I linked those files as well but then got the following error.

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib'
```

So I included that file as well and ran the following command.

```
link main.obj /subsystem:console /entry:main /out:main.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.19041.0\um\x64\kernel32.Lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64\legacy_stdio_definitions.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64\legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\lib\x64\msvcrt.lib"
```

Now I am getting the following errors and my current theory is that I need to link more files but can't figure out which ones.

```
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.29.30148.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __acrt_iob_func referenced in function _vwprintf_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfwprintf referenced in function _vfwprintf_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfwprintf_s referenced in function _vfwprintf_s_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfwprintf_p referenced in function _vfwprintf_p_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfwscanf referenced in function _vfwscanf_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vswprintf referenced in function _vsnwprintf_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vswprintf_s referenced in function _vswprintf_s_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsnwprintf_s referenced in function _vsnwprintf_s_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vswprintf_p referenced in function _vswprintf_p_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vswscanf referenced in function _vswscanf_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf referenced in function _vfprintf_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf_s referenced in function _vfprintf_s_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfprintf_p referenced in function _vfprintf_p_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vfscanf referenced in function _vfscanf_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf referenced in function _vsnprintf_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf_s referenced in function _vsprintf_s_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsnprintf_s referenced in function _vsnprintf_s_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsprintf_p referenced in function _vsprintf_p_l
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib(legacy_stdio_definitions.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __stdio_common_vsscanf referenced in function _vsscanf_l
main.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 19 unresolved externals
```

At this point I ditched `link.exe` and use `gcc` to compile my code and it successfully compiled!

```
gcc main.obj -o main.exe
```

---

## **My questions**

- What can I do to link my object files using `link.exe`.
- Trying to figure out a solution I came across the following compilers and linkers, some of them I was a little familiar with, and some of them were a new discovery to me.

  1. `ml64`
  2. `link`
  3. `gcc`
  4. `ld`
  5. `cl`

  Some of them are microsoft compilers and linkers some are gnu compilers and linkers. What are the differences between these compilers and linkers and when should I use which ones? (I use a windows amd machine if that's needed)
- The assembly code that I have provided here is the one that I copied from a book with some changes. In that book the author was linking an assembly compiled `.obj` file and a `C` compiled `.obj` and was calling the function in `C` defined in `assembly` to write `Hello, World!` in the console. I made some changes here to make this a standalone `assembly` program but still don't understand the program properly, e.g., what is the use of `sub` and `add` instructions. So a brief explanation of the program will be appreciated.
- I noticed that there is an `entry` flag available to us in `link`. My assumption for now is that is specifies where the program/instructions begin. So, if I replaced all the `main` keywords in the assembly code with let's say `start` and used `/entry:start` as one of the flags, will the program compile and work as intended? (assuming that I managed to compile the program using `link` in the first place)

Comment: you need add *ucrt.lib*

Comment: It worked but now is giving the following warning
`legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib(legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.obj) : warning LNK4210: .CRT section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators`

Comment: yes, correct. because you need `/merge:.CRT=.rdata` and call `_initterm`

Comment: adding the merge flag gets rid of compile warning, but when I call `_initterm` in the program, `"Hello, World!"` stops printing. Just using the `merge:.CRT=.rdata` works. Can you explain what exactly the flag does?

Answer (score 1):

the [`printf` / `wprintf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/printf-printf-l-wprintf-wprintf-l?view=msvc-170) - this is part of CRT - and for use it - need do some additional steps. here can be 3 solutions:

1.
not use `printf` / `wprintf` and CRT at all. use only win32 api. use [`WriteConsoleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole). the asm code can be

```
extern __imp__getch:qword
extern __imp_ExitProcess:qword
extern __imp_GetStdHandle:qword
extern __imp_WriteConsoleW:qword
    
.const

;; Hello, world!

msg@@Len = 0eH
ALIGN 2
msg:
DW 0048h, 0065h, 006Ch, 006Ch, 006Fh, 002Ch, 0020h, 0077h
DW 006Fh, 0072h, 006Ch, 0064h, 0021h, 000Ah

.code
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = -11

AnyName proc
    sub rsp, 28h
    
    mov rcx, STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE 
    call __imp_GetStdHandle
    mov rcx, rax
    lea rdx, msg
    mov r8, msg@@Len
    lea r9, [rsp + 20h]
    mov qword ptr[rsp + 20h], 0
    call __imp_WriteConsoleW
   
    call __imp__getch
    
    call __imp_ExitProcess
    
    add rsp, 28h
    ret
AnyName endp

end
```

compile it:

```
ml64 /c /Cp /Zp16 main.asm
```

and build:

```
link main.obj 
/subsystem:console 
/entry:AnyName 
/out:main.exe 
/map 
/MANIFEST:NO 
/NOLOGO 
/NODEFAULTLIB 
/DEBUG 
/OPT:REF 
/OPT:ICF 
/MACHINE:X64 
/EMITPOGOPHASEINFO 
/LIBPATH:"..." 
kernel32.Lib ucrt.lib > build_log.txt
```

note that here used only 2 lib - kernel32.Lib and ucrt.lib (for `_getch` ). final exe size is near 2.5Kb
call `ExitProcess` is mandatory - otherwise your exe not terminate at all or terminate say after 30 seconds. the exe entry point can have anyname.

2.

if we want use CRT - it must be initialized. the exe entry point must be `[w]mainCRTStartup` in this case and or code must have proc `[w]main`. it will be called from `[w]mainCRTStartup`

asm code

```
extern __imp__getch:qword
extern __imp_wprintf:qword
    
.const

;; Hello, world!

msg@@Len = 0eH
ALIGN 2
msg:
DW 0048h, 0065h, 006Ch, 006Ch, 006Fh, 002Ch, 0020h, 0077h
DW 006Fh, 0072h, 006Ch, 0064h, 0021h, 000Ah

.code

wmain proc
    sub rsp, 28h
    
    lea rcx, msg
    call __imp_wprintf
   
    call __imp__getch
        
    add rsp, 28h
    ret
wmain endp

end
```

note that here we must not call `ExitProcess` - we return to CRT code, which by self call it. for link we need now set

```
/entry:wmainCRTStartup
```

and list of libs:

```
kernel32.Lib 
ucrt.lib 
vcruntime.lib 
msvcrt.lib 
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib 
legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib
```

source code became less and more simply compare first variant, but binary exe not take 9Kb+ in size (compare 2.5Kb infirst variant)

3.
partialy use CRT (most complex variant). use CRT functions like `wprintf` but initialize CRT by self

```
OPTION DOTNAME

extern __imp__getch:qword
extern __imp_wprintf:qword
extern __imp__initterm:qword
extern __imp_ExitProcess:qword
    
.CRT$XIA SEGMENT READONLY PARA 'CONST'
__xi_a DQ 0
.CRT$XIA ENDS

.CRT$XIZ SEGMENT READONLY PARA 'CONST'
__xi_z DQ 0
.CRT$XIZ ENDS

.const

;; Hello, world!

msg@@Len = 0eH
ALIGN 2
msg:
DW 0048h, 0065h, 006Ch, 006Ch, 006Fh, 002Ch, 0020h, 0077h
DW 006Fh, 0072h, 006Ch, 0064h, 0021h, 000Ah

.code

AnyName proc
    sub rsp, 28h
    
    lea rcx, __xi_a
    lea rdx, __xi_z
    call __imp__initterm
    
    lea rcx, msg
    call __imp_wprintf
   
    call __imp__getch
    
    call __imp_ExitProcess
        
    add rsp, 28h
    ret
AnyName endp

end
```

what here is changed ? at first we again set entry point to self code:

```
/entry:AnyName
```

we again need direct call `ExitProcess`. the list of libs became smaller

```
kernel32.Lib 
ucrt.lib 
legacy_stdio_definitions.lib 
legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib
```

we can remove `vcruntime.lib` and `msvcrt.lib`  - they unused here

and need add option for linker

```
/merge:.CRT=.rdata
```

question - for what this option and for what call to `_initterm` , `.CRT$XIA`, `.CRT$XIZ`, etc ?

[When Microsoft C/C++ compiler sees a global initializer, it generates a dynamic initializer and place function pointers to it in special sections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-initialization?view=msvc-170). names of this section you can view in *initializers.cpp* (usually this file is located in *`\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\<version>\crt\src\vcruntime\initializers.cpp`* )
fragment fom it:

```
extern "C" _CRTALLOC(".CRT$XIA") _PIFV __xi_a[] = { nullptr }; // C initializers (first)
extern "C" _CRTALLOC(".CRT$XIZ") _PIFV __xi_z[] = { nullptr }; // C initializers (last)
extern "C" _CRTALLOC(".CRT$XCA") _PVFV __xc_a[] = { nullptr }; // C++ initializers (first)
extern "C" _CRTALLOC(".CRT$XCZ") _PVFV __xc_z[] = { nullptr }; // C++ initializers (last)
extern "C" _CRTALLOC(".CRT$XPA") _PVFV __xp_a[] = { nullptr }; // C pre-terminators (first)
extern "C" _CRTALLOC(".CRT$XPZ") _PVFV __xp_z[] = { nullptr }; // C pre-terminators (last)
extern "C" _CRTALLOC(".CRT$XTA") _PVFV __xt_a[] = { nullptr }; // C terminators (first)
extern "C" _CRTALLOC(".CRT$XTZ") _PVFV __xt_z[] = { nullptr }; // C terminators (last)

#pragma comment(linker, "/merge:.CRT=.rdata")
```

when linker view `.CRT*` section it always generate warning:

```
LNK4210: .CRT section exists; there may be unhandled static initializers or terminators
```

when we use CRT as usual - the initializers.cpp by fact is included (via ob/lib) and `#pragma comment(linker, "/merge:.CRT=.rdata")` remove `.CRT` section. if we not use CRT - need by self do this. not only merge sections, but call all function pointers - by call [`_initterm`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/initterm-initterm-e?view=msvc-170)

if we use `/map` option we can view symbol

`__PLEASE_LINK_WITH_legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib` (yes, exactly with such name). it come from `legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib` and located in `.CRT$XIC` section. so this is function pointer and need call it. if interesting how this symbol is generated and which code will be called - look for `\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\<version>\crt\src\linkopts\legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.cpp`

it fragment:

```
static int __CRTDECL initialize_legacy_wide_specifiers() noexcept
{
    _CRT_INTERNAL_LOCAL_PRINTF_OPTIONS |= _CRT_INTERNAL_PRINTF_LEGACY_WIDE_SPECIFIERS;
    _CRT_INTERNAL_LOCAL_SCANF_OPTIONS  |= _CRT_INTERNAL_SCANF_LEGACY_WIDE_SPECIFIERS;
    return 0;
}

    #pragma warning(disable: 4483) // Allow use of __identifier
    extern "C" _CRTALLOC(".CRT$XIC") _PIFV __identifier("__PLEASE_LINK_WITH_legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib") = initialize_legacy_wide_specifiers;
```

final size of exe in 3 case will be near 3.5Kb